# How do I style the header alone and put pics either side and add social media icons and center it

Tags: html, css

Newbie to creating a website from scratch, For some reason 2 of my pics(png) sit side by side which is correct but I want a space between h1 and png files, their too close together? Secondly, how do I insert the social media icons because it just drops below the header I want them above the title and 2 icons within header but just above title in top right corner? And how do I center the title and 2 icons which sit side by side?

Here is my html code

```
<header
<div class="header">
<h1><img src="s-l300.png" width="100" height=100" class="left-icon">  Explore Russia  <img src="s-l300.png" width="100" height=100" class="right-icon"></h1>
<!-- Add font awesome icons -->
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
</div>
</header>
```

Here is my css code:

```
    /*Format Header Title */
h1 {
  text-decoration:overline;
  text-color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align:center;
  font-size:50px;
  font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif  text-decoration: overline;
}

/*Format Header */
.header {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 30px;
    animation-name: flash;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-play-state: running;
    vertical-align:center;
}
```

Comment: You have errors in your HTML (missing > after <header) and in your CSS (vertical-align does not have `center` and there's a missing ; after sans-serif). Does it help if you correct those?

Comment: There are multiple errors in Gnanavel's answer (css and html). You should seriously fix those. Headers shouldn't contain images. That's bad practise and you'll have SEO issues as well. Get the markup right at an this early stage.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  text-decoration:overline;
  color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align:center;
  font-size:50px;
  font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif  text-decoration: overline;
  text-align: center;
}

/*Format Header */
.header {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 30px;
  animation-name: flash;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-play-state: running;
  vertical-align:center;
  position: relative;
}
.header .left-icon{
  margin-right:10px;
}
.header .right-icon{
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.social-icons{
  position: absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
}
.social-icons a{
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <h1><img src="s-l300.png" width="100" height="100" class="left-icon">  Explore Russia  <img src="s-l300.png" width="100" height="100" class="right-icon"></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="social-icons">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not put images inside the Header tags. You can use flexbox to place the images on either side of your header. Also there are issues in your font type styling. See fixed example below.

```css
.header-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.icon-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.icon-wrapper a {
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-wrapper img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 30px;
  animation-name: flash;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: overline;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 34px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <img src="s-l300.png" />
    <h1>Explore Russia </h1>
    <img src="s-l300.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="icon-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

check ccs flexbox styling principle. it will answer all your questions about items alignment